# If a killed Saiyan is revived does he/she receive a zenkai boost?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z

Zenkai boosts are given to Saiyans for near death experiences that they survive. What happens though if they actually die and are revived?

Comment: I dont think there is any info about it but the general consensus seems to be no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A zenkai boost is given by damage received so not neccesarily a near-death experience. But near death is probably one of the highest possible boosts obtainable. [I highly suggest reading this for more info about zenkai.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Saiyan_Power) So to come back at your question it depends on how they are revived. For example if they are still damaged and in a near-death state their zenkai boost will be extremely strong. But if they are revived fully recovered with almost no damage then their zenkai boost will be very low. If they are recovered with no damage at all then they wont have a zenkai boost.